# How to process complex data in ArrayType using Spark functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

There is a json data source. Here is an example of one row:

```
{
  "PrimaryAcctNumber": "account1",
  "AdditionalData": [
    {
      "Addrs": [
        "an address for account1",
        "the longest address in the address list for account1",
        "another address for account1"
      ],
      "AccountNumber": "Account1",
      "IP": 2368971684
    },
    {
      "Addrs": [
        "an address for account2",
        "the longest address in the address list for account2",
        "another address for account2"
      ],
      "AccountNumber": "Account2",
      "IP": 9864766814
    }
  ]
}
```

So when load it to spark DataFrame, the schema is:

```
root
 |-- PrimaryAcctNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AdditionalData: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
```

I want to use Spark to create a new column called `LongestAddressOfPrimaryAccount` based on colomn `AdditionalData (ArrayType[StructType])` using the following logic:

- Iterate AdditionalData

  - If `AccountNumber` property equals `PrimaryAcctNumber` of the row, the value of `LongestAddressOfPrimaryAccount` will be the longest string in `Addrs` array
  - If no `AccountNumber` property equals `PrimaryAcctNumber`, the value will be "N/A"

So for the given row above, the expected output is:

```
{
  "PrimaryAcctNumber": "account1",
  "AdditionalData": [
    {
      "Addrs": [
        "an address for account1",
        "the longest address in the address list for account1",
        "another address for account1"
      ],
      "AccountNumber": "Account1",
      "IP": 2368971684
    },
    {
      "Addrs": [
        "an address for account2",
        "the longest address in the address list for account2",
        "another address for account2"
      ],
      "AccountNumber": "Account2",
      "IP": 9864766814
    }
  ],
  "LongestAddressOfPrimaryAccount": "the longest address in the address list for account1"
}
```

It is doable to use a UDF or a map function. But that is not the best practice for Spark.

Is it doable to just use Spark functions? Something like:

```
sourceDdf.withColumn("LongestAddressOfPrimaryAccount", coalesce(
  longest(
    get_field(iterate_array_for_match($"AdditionalData", "AccountNumber", $"PrimaryAcctNumber"), "Addrs")
  )
  , lit("N/A")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write a `udf` function for the requirement you have if you have spark versions 2.2 or less than that as *inbuilt functions* would be *more complex and slower* (*slower in the sense that you will have to combine more inbuilt functions*) than using a `udf` function. And I am not aware of such inbuilt function that can meet your requirement directly.

Databricks team is working on [Nested Data Using Higher Order Functions in SQL](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/24/working-with-nested-data-using-higher-order-functions-in-sql-on-databricks.html) and those would be in the next releases.

Until then you will have to write `udf` function if you don't want to your work to be complex.

Comment: I am for sure using the latest Spark release version. Thanks for the guide.